# Is there a way to check for a valid CSS style name using the CSS supports API?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There's a sortof new API called [CSS.supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports). It checks if a style is valid.

Is there a way to use this API to check if a CSS style itself is exists at all?

Is there something better than:

```
("color" in new HTMLElement().style)
```

What I want:

```
var result = CSS.supports("colour");  // false
var result = CSS.supports("color");   // true
```

**Requirements:**

- That a CSS style exists at all. This is for checking for typos.
- I can't pass in a value because the value may return false even if the style exists

**Background:**
I'm doing some syntax highlighting and want to indicate to the user that a style may be a typo. I do not care if it is a valid style value only that the style exists at all in the W3C CSS specification.

**Example:**
If the user types, "colour" I want the API to return false. If they type "color" then return true.

Comment: Actually, the API checks whether the browsers supports a property and value. If they are invalid according to the standard, the method will always return false. And what are you trying to achieve checking for `color`?  It’s part of CSS Level 1 from 1196. Can you be more precise? `CSS.supports('color', 'black')`does work.

Comment: @Andy I want to check that a CSS property name is valid not the value. So, if the user types, "colour" instead of "color" it will return false. I want to check for any CSS property style. I do not care about the style value. Giving the style value at this time.

Comment: Given that "initial" is always supported for every property, can't you just make that the second parameter?

Comment: Are you trying to check users’ CSS for formal validity? `CSS.supports()` is not a reliable API to check whether CSS properties are *valid* with respect to the standard. It only checks *support* by the user’s current browser version. Is that what you want?

Comment: well. If you’re checking user’s CSS, it’s invalid if they don’t type a value, right? So why can’t you provide property *and* value to the function?

Comment: @Alohci That might work. I'll give it a test run.

Comment: @Alohci It appears that some styles do not like that value. For example,  `CSS.supports("alignContent", "initial")` returns false

Comment: @Andy I'm doing a very basic hint to the user for the style name for syntax highlighting. Consider CSS stylesheet in VSCode. I might underline the style name if the style name is not valid but I don't care about the style value because that could be anything and if I do want to I can use the supports API for validating that. but bc the user can set the style value then CSS.supports might return false for valid style names and new features would fail in older browsers so false positives

Comment: @1.21gigawatts - That appears to be a separate matter. CSS.supports takes css property names, not their camel cased mappings. so `CSS.supports("align-content", "initial")` returns true.

Comment: @Alohci good catch! how do we know that `initial` is a default for all styles? is it in a base class or something? if that's the case then i think it will work

Comment: @Alohci I see MDN mentions it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial

Comment: @1.21gigawatts you still didn’t confirm that you don’t care about the fact that you are checking for support in the user’s browser instead of formal validity of their styles. It’s a hack.

Comment: @Andy If it exists as a property on the style object that is good enough for my purposes. Last I checked all styles are on the HTMLElement.style object but maybe not. If you know of an updated list of all valid style names I’d love to hear about it

Comment: My point is that you can only check if it's in the style object _of the current browser_. If the user's browser is late in implementing it, it will be invalid.

Comment: @andy I know. The `CSS.supports()` and the `(property in element.style)` both have that issue. That's the topic of this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own utility function that does what you are looking to do.

```js
// You could name this anything you want as long as the property name doesn't already exist.
CSS.isPropertyValid = function(prop) { return prop in document.body.style; } 

CSS.isPropertyValid('color'); // true
CSS.isPropertyValid('colors'); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Let’s distinguish between *supported* and *validity*.

A property name is *valid* if it is defined in the CSS standard (maybe at a certain [level of maturity](https://www.w3.org/2021/Process-20211102/#maturity-levels)).

`CSS.supports()` checks if a style is *supported* by the browser (or runtime) used.

Just as `prop in document.body.style`, it is browser-dependent and might reject completely valid CSS properties that are not yet implemented in the user’s browser – or allow browser-specific properties that are not yet or will never be in the standard.

Since W3C standards become a *Recommendation* only if there are at least two independent implementations, and because there is only two browser engines left, it is likely that this check suffices.

So you could use [the universal `initial` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) along with the `CSS.supports()` method to only check for semi-validity of the property:

> It can be applied to any CSS property.

```js
CSS.supports(userProp, "initial");
```

### Real syntax checking

IDE’s syntax checkers usually work based on a grammar, which is published alongside the full-text standard, or built based on them.

Such grammar is often defined in [the Backus–Naur form (BNF)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form). You often find them in RFC standards as well.

```
style-rule ::=
    selectors-list {
      properties-list
    }

selectors-list ::=
    selector[:pseudo-class] [::pseudo-element]
    [, selectors-list]

properties-list ::=
    [property : value] [; properties-list]
```

See [the Grammar of CSS 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#grammar) for an example, or [`addr-spec` from RFC5322](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#page-18)

You can use a definition of a language like this to generate a syntax checker. This is known as a [compiler-compiler](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler). Somebody probably has done that already for CSS and published a syntax checker library for CSS, and keeping it up-to-date with the W3C recommendations.

### Is there a syntax check API in browsers?

I don’ think so. Browser engines are implemented in a very forgiving way. If browsers don’t understand a CSS statement, they will ignore it. That’s why we can write CSS progressively.

Another example is HTML. While it can be defined as XML and formally checked for syntax correctness, browsers accept and render any crap that resembles the standard.

So for CSS, browsers are more likely to internally check for support, not validity, since practically, it doesn’t even matter if a CSS property is valid, if the browser cannot render it.

That’s my theory. Any clarifying comments are welcome (:

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question with more details. It's true that browsers would check for support not validity. So based on our conversation you could add, "At this time, the CSS.supports API doesn't tell if a style name is a valid style listed in the CSS specification."